# Lock on two tables without dependences between them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, blocking, read-committed

I have a strange situation. I'm working on a SQL Server 2005 database, I've searched locks on DB using [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/how-to-identify-blocking-problems-with-sql-profiler/).

After capture all day, stop the trace and see the results, I found a blocking query that blocks a insertion, BUT, the query is in read committed isolation and read table A, the insertion try to insert on table B with all values defined.

Anyone knows why the first query is blocking the second one?

I've searched all dependencies on the two tables and haven't found any.

I know that this could be solved changing the isolation level of the select statement, but I want to know why this occurs

Thanks!

Comment: Have you also checked the triggers as well as the functions?

Comment: Yes, the Table B (insert), has 3 triggers, one for Insert, but only updates the same table. I checked on "View Dependencies" for each table and nothing there too.